# How to show NSAlert using Sheet window in separate .XIB files?

Tags: applescript-objc

I have a button to perform a task and if an error occurs during the process a warning is displayed using NSAlert "Sheet window"
in this moment I am using multiple .XIB files in a project, I can't display the "Sheet window" in these files(.XIB) is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

```
on clickedButton:sender

try
--some code here...

on error errorMsg
           set alert to current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
           tell alert
               its setMessageText:"This is an ERROR"
               its setInformativeText: "Error: " & errorMsg
               its setAlertStyle:2
               its beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow modalDelegate:me didEndSelector:(missing value) contextInfo:(missing value)
               end tell
            end try
end clickedButton:
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to show the alert even if you don't have a window to put the sheet onto, just do `beginSheet...` or `runModal` based on the app having a mainWindow.

Comment: @red_menace in this case "theWindow" is a mainWindow.

Comment: If you don't have a mainWindow, `NSApp's mainWindow()` will be missing value (and you won't have a window to put the sheet on), so you can use that to do either `alert's runModal()` or the sheet thing.

Comment: @red_menace, I'm sorry for the stupidity, but could you give me an example with the code above?
I think I'm having a mental block. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a window to put the sheet on, you will need to run the normal alert dialog.  You can test for a window by using `NSApp's mainWindow()`, which will be `missing value` if there isn't one, and do either `alert's runModal()` or the sheet depending on the result:

```
use framework "Cocoa"
use scripting additions

property theWindow : missing value -- this will be the main window...
property sheetOrNot : true -- ... or not, depending on this flag

on run -- this lets the example run from the Script Editor if you forget the main thread thing
    my performSelectorOnMainThread:"doWindow" withObject:(missing value) waitUntilDone:true
    my performSelectorOnMainThread:"doAlert" withObject:(missing value) waitUntilDone:true
end run

on doWindow() -- create a window to play with
    set theWindow to current application's NSWindow's alloc's initWithContentRect:{{200, 400}, {400, 200}} styleMask:7 backing:(current application's NSBackingStoreBuffered) defer:true
    set theWindow's releasedWhenClosed to true
    if sheetOrNot then tell theWindow to makeKeyAndOrderFront:me
end doWindow

on doAlert() -- show the alert
    try
        --some code here...
        error "oops" -- ...that went badly
    on error errorMsg
        set alert to current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
        tell alert
            its setMessageText:"This is an ERROR"
            its setInformativeText:("Error: " & errorMsg)
            its setAlertStyle:2
            if current application's NSApp's mainWindow() is not missing value then
                its beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow modalDelegate:me didEndSelector:(missing value) contextInfo:(missing value)
            else -- no window, so do a normal modal dialog
                its runModal()
            end if
        end tell
    end try
end doAlert
```

Comment: I get it, thanks I thought it was possible to show Sheet Window in a Custom View.
apparently not.

Comment: Sheets are used over windows; if you don't necessarily need an alert dialog, maybe take a look at [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover)?